# asterisk incoming call CID rewrite

Tags: asterisk

I have the following rules set for my german based SIP account (the idea is to have on ALL numbers coming through this Trunk to add 0049 and strip the first 0 so i can callback using the 0049 calling rule and number-matching in the adressbook works much better.

this is the rules I have applied

```
exten=s,1,NoOp(${CALLERID(num)})
exten=s,2,ExecIf($[ "${CALLERID(num)}"="" ],Set,CALLERID(all)=unknown <0000000>)
exten=s,3,ExecIf($["${CALLERID(NUM):0:1}" = "0"],Set(CALLERID(num)=0049${CALLERID(num):1}))
exten=s,4,Goto(ringroups-office-1|s|1)
```

but calls coming in missing the "00" and just showing 49xxxxx 
any idea what that could be?

hard guess: it's something stupid I missed :P

Comment: FYI: Line 2 has a typo:  "Set,CALLERID" should be "Set(CALLERID".

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
exten=s,3,ExecIf($["${CALLERID(NUM):0:1}" = "0"],Set(CALLERID(num)="0049${CALLERID(num):1}"))
```